# Exception in Automapper Mapping and how to frame the class structure properly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I am facing the below issues when I try to achieve the requirement.

1. In controller I have used automapper to map "Viewmodel" class with "Entities" class but I am getting exception.I used Automapper exception class to catch the exception, the result is :

   Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

   Mapping types:

   EmpDetails -> StaffMember
   Org.Entities.EmpDetails -> Org.Web.Models.StaffMember

   Destination path:
   List`1[0]

   Source value:
   Org.Entities.EmpDetails
2. In Data access layer when I am adding the value to dropdown I am getting Exception , Please advise me whether the classes are well formed/designed and help me out to get rid of these issues.

PFB Screen shots and Codes:

**Exception ScreenShots**

**Exception for Automapper in Controller:**

[image: Automapper Exception]

**Exception For DropDown in DAL:**

[image: Dropdown NullReference Exception]

**Code:**

**Controller:-**

```
EmployeeStatus oStatusBL = new EmployeeStatus(); // Business layer class
public ActionResult Index()
{
    EmpStatusDetails oStaff = oStatusBL.getEmpStatusDetails();
    StaffMemberList oLsit = new StaffMemberList();
    Mapper.CreateMap<EmpStatusDetails, StaffMemberList>();
    Mapper.Map<EmpStatusDetails, StaffMemberList>(oStaff); // Exception Occurs here
    ViewBag.StateDropDown = oStatusBL.GetStateDropDown();
    return View(oLsit);
}
```

**ViewModel:-**

```
public class StaffMember
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string FullAddress { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}

public class StaffMemberList
{
    public List<StaffMember> StaffDetails { get; set; }
    public Status StatusDetails { get; set; }
    public Users UserDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Name")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status Message is Required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[\w\d]+$", ErrorMessage = "Avoid Special characters")]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Exceeds 250 Character")]
    public string Statusmessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownNameList { get; set; }
}

public class Users
{ 
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is Required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s,'-]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Address")]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Exceeds 250 Character")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is Required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid City")]
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Exceeds 150 Character")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is Required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip is Required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{5}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zipcode")]
    public int? Zip { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

**EntitiesLayer:-**

```
public class EmpDetails
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string FullAddress { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public StatusEntity StatusDetails { get; set; }
}

public class EmpStatusDetails
{
    public List<EmpDetails> StaffDetails { get; set; }
    public StatusEntity StatusDetails { get; set; }
    public UserEntity UserDetails { get; set; }
}

public class StatusEntity
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Statusmessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownNameList { get; set; }
}

public class UserEntity
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int? Zip { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

**BusinessLayer:-**

```
    StaffDetailsDAL oDal = new StaffDetailsDAL();
    public EmpStatusDetails getEmpStatusDetails()
    {
        return oDal.EmployeeStatusAndDetails();
    }
```

**DataAccessLayer:-**

```
public EmpStatusDetails EmployeeStatusAndDetails()
{
    EmpStatusDetails oEmp = new EmpStatusDetails(); // Entity layer class
    List<User> us = dbContext.Users.Select(o => o).ToList();

    List<EmpDetails> oStaffList = (from usrs in dbContext.Users
               join stats in dbContext.StatusUpdates on usrs.UserID equals stats.UserID 
               where stats.Statusmessage !=null
                                   select new EmpDetails { FullName = usrs.FirstName + " " + usrs.LastName, FullAddress = usrs.Address + "," + usrs.State + "," + usrs.City + "," + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)usrs.Zip), StatusMessage = stats.Statusmessage, DateCreated = (DateTime)stats.DateCreated, UserID = usrs.UserID }
               ).OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated).ToList<EmpDetails>();
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> oList = (from val in oStaffList
                                  select new SelectListItem { Text = val.FullName, Value = val.UserID.ToString() }).ToList();
    oEmp.StaffDetails = oStaffList;
    oEmp.StatusDetails.DropDownNameList = oList;  // Exception Occurs here
    return oEmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a mapping for the collection of StaffDetails